# Application Insights Live Stream

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

What is the minimum "bare-bones" that you need to do in order to get the Live Stream working with the latest App Insights SDKs (2.x) on .NET Core? Do you *need* to deploy the appinsights.config file? And if so, what elements need to be in there? Alternatively, can you do it with a code-first approach, and if so, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://apmtips.com/blog/2017/02/13/enable-application-insights-live-metrics-from-code/

```
TelemetryConfiguration configuration = new TelemetryConfiguration();
configuration.InstrumentationKey = "9d3ebb4f-7a11-4fb1-91ac-7ca8a17a27eb";

QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor processor = null;

configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
    .Use((next) =>
    {
        processor = new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next);
        return processor;
    })
    .Build();

var QuickPulse = new QuickPulseTelemetryModule();
QuickPulse.Initialize(configuration);
QuickPulse.RegisterTelemetryProcessor(processor);
```

Comment: Worked first time (even after porting to F#!) - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apps on latest .NET Core AI SDK should get Live Stream automatically.

If it isn't working then it might be some misconfiguration. One approach is to open a github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore

Comment: Thanks but that's basically what I already know. And it's not appropriate to raise an issue on the repo - it's not an issue, this is just about education.

Comment: Is your question about "How to leave only Live Stream working but disable everything else"? Or is it about how to enable Live Stream with minimum efforts?

Comment: Re: github issues. We have lots of issues tagged "question" and provide detailed guidance if needed. Feel free to leave it as an issue =)

Comment: Thanks :) It wasn't about turning everything else off, but simply what is needed to turn it on. Forget about the NuGet tooling that magically copies stuff across - imagine I have a simple console application (or web app, whatever) and I've got the AI assembly referenced. What is needed to turn live stream on.